# RegExp for matching if a text has only one type of letter, example “KKKK”

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex that matches if a text has only one type of letter? Example: "KKKKK", "AAAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"

Comment: Which language/tool do you use? Does it support backreferences in the regex?

Comment: [`/^([a-zA-Z])\1*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/D5cKsx/1) ... for word match set word boundary [`/\b([a-zA-Z])\1*\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/D5cKsx/2)

Comment: anchors forgetted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using groups and back-references.

My examples are in Java's regex dialogue, but you can adapt it to any dialect that supports back-references. For example some engines need `\(...\)` instead of `(...)`.

First you need a group, which you denote by surrounding in parentheses:

```
(.)
```

This matches any single character. If you want it to specifically be upper-case letters, you could use `(A-Z)` instead.

Next you need to match a second character that is the same as the contents of the group. You can *back-reference* the contents of the first match using `\1`:

```
(.)\1
```

This will match `AA` or `BB` but not `AB`. And not `A`, since the second character is compulsory.

Next you need to specify that the second character occurs any number of times, including zero. That's done with `*`.

```
(.)\1*
```

This matches `A`, `B`, `AA`, `BB`, `AAA`, `BBBBBBB` but not `AB` or `AAB`.

In Java, the `\` has to be escaped:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");
```

Your regex engine might:
  - use this to search the input string for a part that matches (so `BAAAAB` matches -- it finds the `AAAA`)
  - or it might require the whole string to match the pattern (so `BAAAAB` does not match).

If you want the second behaviour from an engine that does the first, add `.*` either side of the pattern.

If you want the first behaviour from an engine that does the second, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern, these match the start and end of the line, respectively.